# Why was the <hgroup> tag added to HTML5?

Tags: html

Why was the `<hgroup>` tag added to HTML5? What’s their technical usage? What’s the grouping advantage?

Comment: Note that `<hgroup>` is ‘Being considered for removal’ currently, http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-hgroup-element

Comment: or more details here: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-admin/2013Apr/0003.html

Answer (score 1):

It gives more defined selection, eg:

```
h1 {font-size:5em}                   output: font-size 5em
h2 {font-size:2em; color: black}     outout: font-size 2em, black
```

using them in a hgroup, you would get

```
hgroup h1 {font-size:3em}            output: font-size:3em
hgroup h2 {color:grey}               output: font-size:2em (from above defined), grey
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with headers and their 'levels' arises when you generate dynamic content. Let's say you have a more or less fixed H1 and H2 combo and the page, and you have an article section with dynamic content that comes from a rich editor.

Traditionally it would be problematic at best to try and guess which header leveles to allow in the editor markup.

I haven't studied the hgroup element in detail, but I have read the article above and others, and it seems logical to me that the hgroup element can be used to 'reset' the level numbering, so that dynamic content in a rich editor can start using H1.

Comment: I don’t think it’s the `<hgroup>` element that allows you to use `<h1>` anywhere — that’s more the `<section>` element and the outlining algorithm. `<hgroup>` lets you combine e.g. an `<h2>` and an `<h3>` into one heading, so they’re considered as a single heading in the outline.